# maemo scratchbox compiler error with gtk+-2.0

Tags: c, compiler-construction, maemo, scratchbox

I'm trying to follow section 3.4.2, starting on page 31 of [this manual](http://maemo.org/maemo_release_documentation/maemo4.1.x/Maemo_Diablo_Reference_Manual_for_maemo_4.1.pdf). However, as I have configured my target to be DIABLO_ARMEL rather than DIABLO_X86, I have gotten different results for this command:

```
[sbox-DIABLO_X86: ~] > gcc -Wall -g gtk_helloworld-1.c \
 ‘pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0‘ -o gtk_helloworld-1 \
 ‘pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0‘
[sbox-DIABLO_X86: ~] >
```

I have checked the cflags and libs results of the commands in single quotes before entering this line, and the results between what were described in the example and what I saw in the command window.

Anyhow, I'm not expected to have error messages popping up in the terminal, but I got the following:

```
[sbox-DIABLO_ARMEL: ~] > gcc -Wall -g gtk-helloworld-1.c \
> 'pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0' -o gtk_helloworld-1 \
> 'pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0'
sbox-arm-linux-gcc: pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0: No such file or directory
sbox-arm-linux-gcc: pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0: No such file or directory
gtk-helloworld-1.c:15:21: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
gtk-helloworld-1.c: In function `main':
gtk-helloworld-1.c:20: error: `GtkWindow' undeclared (first use in this function)
gtk-helloworld-1.c:20: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
gtk-helloworld-1.c:20: error: for each function it appears in.)
gtk-helloworld-1.c:20: error: `window' undeclared (first use in this function)
gtk-helloworld-1.c:21: error: `GtkLabel' undeclared (first use in this function)
gtk-helloworld-1.c:21: error: `label' undeclared (first use in this function)
gtk-helloworld-1.c:24: warning: implicit declaration of function `gtk_init'
gtk-helloworld-1.c:28: warning: implicit declaration of function `g_object_new'
gtk-helloworld-1.c:28: error: `GTK_TYPE_WINDOW' undeclared (first use in this function)
gtk-helloworld-1.c:34: error: `GTK_TYPE_LABEL' undeclared (first use in this function)
gtk-helloworld-1.c:39: warning: implicit declaration of function `gtk_container_add'
gtk-helloworld-1.c:39: warning: implicit declaration of function `GTK_CONTAINER'
gtk-helloworld-1.c:39: warning: implicit declaration of function `GTK_WIDGET'
gtk-helloworld-1.c:42: warning: implicit declaration of function `gtk_widget_show_all'
gtk-helloworld-1.c:45: warning: implicit declaration of function `g_print'
gtk-helloworld-1.c:46: warning: implicit declaration of function `gtk_main'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in terms of the include and library path configurations. It would be great if someone can provide some tips on fixing this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need back-quotes around pkg-config:

```
gcc -Wall -g gtk-helloworld-1.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`... -o gtk ...
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood your suggestion, but I tried to type **gcc -Wall -g gtk-helloworld-1.c 'pkg-config --cflgas gtk+-2.0' -o gtk-helloworld-1 'pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0'** all in one line and still failed to build the program. I'm going to check whether I have the correct package.

Comment: you forgot the back-quotes again...

' is a quote
` is a back-quote

:)

Comment: Or if the backticks are problem, run pkg-config with syntax like this: $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0)